# Momentum conservation: Will the cart move?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

I know the law of conservation of linear momentum.

I thought of the following situation. A block at some height is made to fall freely on a cart which is moving with a constant velocity. Will the cart accelerate?

I think the velocity of the cart should not change because the (cart + block) system is not isolated system because the force of gravity is acting on the block. So we cannot apply the law of conservation of momentum here.

Please provide me the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that the block has a velocity downwards but no horizontal velocity and that the cart is moving along a horizontal surface with no frictional forces acting on it.

The cart and block system have the downward vertical forces of gravitational attraction on them.
The cart also has an upward normal force acting on it due to the surface which is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the gravitational attractive force on it.
At the instant the block hits the cart you can consider the vertical and horizontal motion of the block separately.

An upward normal force on the block due to cart will change the downward momentum of the block to zero and when the block is moving on top of the cart it will have no net vertical force acting on it.

For the block and cart system which has no horizontal external forces acting on it the horizontal momentum of the system must be conserved.
This will mean that during the collision between the block and the cart the block will increase its horizontal velocity (from zero) in the direction of the motion of the cart and the cart's horizontal velocity will decrease until the block and cart are not moving relative to one another.
When this happens the horizontal momentum of the cart and block will equal the initial horizontal momentum of the block as there are no horizontal external forces acting on the block and cart system.

**Update** as a result of a comment

The horizontal momentum of the cart decreases but the horizontal momentum of the block increases by the same amount so the total horizontal momentum of the block and cart system does not change.

For the system which consists of the block and cart there are no horizontal external forces but there must be horizontal internal forces which reduce the horizontal velocity (momentum) of the cart and increase the horizontal velocity (momentum) of the block.
These internal kinetic friction forces arise because there must be relative movement between the block and the cart when they are first in contact as they cannot undergo an infinite acceleration ie get to the final state of both moving with the same velocity instantaneously.
That being so although the horizontal momentum of the system is conserved there is a reduction in the kinetic energy of the system ie the collision between the block and the cart is inelastic and heat will be generated.

Comment: I have one doubt. The net result is that the cart's velocity decreases . Is this only because of the momentum conservation or there is some external horizontal force on the cart when the block drops on it which causes the cart to decelerate .

Comment: @AshokSharma I have updated my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: "The cart also has an upward normal reaction forces acting on it due to the surface which is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the gravitational attractive force on it." ** Don't say that !!!** It's misleading to beginners! The normal force is not a "reaction" force. It is an electromagnetic force due to interaction of the two surfaces.  It is independent of the gravitational force.  We can calculate that it happens to be equal in magnitude to the weight of the cart, because we know the vertical acceleration is zero, but it is NOT the Newton's 3rd Law pair force to the weight.

Comment: @BillN Point taken and I have removed the word “reaction” from my answer. If you find any more please remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontal momentum is conserved in a gravitational field. The initial horizontal momentum of the box is zero.  The horizontal momentum of the box plus cart has to equal the original momentum of the cart assuming no dissipative forces. Therefore the horizontal velocity of the cart plus box will be less than the original velocity of the cart.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that no frictional forces are acting on the cart(M).So the cart is moving with constant velocity(v).Now a block(m)falls on the cart with a certain velocity in the downward direction(assuming that the block has no horizontal component of velocity). Now we know that momentum is conserved only when the net 'external' force on the system is zero.In the vertical direction gravity is acting on the system and hence we cannot conserve momentum,however in the horizontal direction in the absence of frictional forces we can conserve momentum and we find that the cart and block now move together with a certain velocity u=Mv/(M+m).Now think about this,velocity of the cart has decreased which implies that it has undergone deceleration,which is caused by the frictional force(an internal force as it acts both on the cart as well as the block) in between the cart and the block which comes into play in order to keep the x coordinate of the centre of mass of the system undisturbed.As a result of this force the block has also undergone acceleration,notice that it has developed a velocity in the horizontal direction from it's previously vertical velocity.
So the answer to your question is basically we can conserve momentum in certain directions where the net 'external'force acting on the system is zero.